# pip list ImportError: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, rhel6

I have a virtual environment that has a python installation in it. I an running RHEL 6.8 and when I source the virtual environment on my RHEL machine and run most pip related commands I am seeing this.

I was able to source this virtual environment on other machines that are running RHEL 6.7 and 6.6 not sure if something is different in 6.8 or really what is happening here.

```
pip list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ws/mastarke-sjc/pyats2/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/ws/mastarke-sjc/pyats2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/ws/mastarke-sjc/pyats2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "/auto/pysw/cel63/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 15, in <module>
    import binascii
ImportError: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `yum install zlib`? But your paths look different than the default ones. It's possible that it's already installed, you only need to add its path to *${LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH}* before starting *python* (or *pip*).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I gave it a try and got this. Package zlib-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: for the LD_LIBRARY_PATH we generally set it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/X11R6/lib for our setup. This is what is working on my other two machines that use this virtual env. When I set this to the latest machine it still gives erros.

Comment: One other thing I wanted to add is I added other zlib packages now when I check I have these packages rpm -qa | grep zlib
zlib-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64
zlib-1.2.3-29.el6.i686
zlib-devel-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64  this is identical to what my other machines have. Looks like this also changed the error message to ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler'

Comment: looks like your correct my issue seems to be related me missing zlib packages. looks like I needed the following yum install zlib.i686. I do hit another error but seems related to openssl which ill look to resolve elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, so you have the 32bit *python*. In that case you'll have to install all the 32bit software that it depends on (could be the same case for *OpenSSL*).